# Dynamical system with only one chain component

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ be a surjective map.

A finite sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{k}$ is called $\varepsilon$-chain if $d(f(x_n), x_{n+1})<\varepsilon$ for $n=0, \ldots k-1$.

We say that the point $x$ is chain recurrent if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $\varepsilon$-chain $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{k}$ with $x_0=x_k=x$; and denote by $R(f)$ el set of chain recurrent points.

I am interested in the veracity of the following statement: If $R(f)$ is connected, then $X=R(f)$.

I would greatly appreciate some counterexample or suggestion for the proof of it.

Comment: [Evgeny](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/87697/evgeny) pointed that [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125737/chain-recurrent-set-of-a-isometry) question at MathOverflow seems to be applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is true and can be proved along the following lines:

1. For $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ put $p_n = f^{(n)}(x)$. By compactness, the
   sequence $\{p_n\}$ has a cluster point $p$. From $\{p_n\}$ we can construct
   $\delta$-chains showing that $p$ is chain-recurrent, i.e. $p \in R(f)$.
   Also, for any given $\varepsilon$, a sufficiently long initial segment of
   $\{p_n\}$ gives us an $\varepsilon$-chain from $x$ to $p$.
2. Since $f$ is surjective, there is a sequence $\{q_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$
   such that $f(q_{n+1}) = q_n$ and $q_0 = x$. Again, $\{q_n\}$ has a cluster point $q$ and 
   again, $q\in R(f)$. This time reversing an initial segment of $\{q_n\}$
   gives us an $\varepsilon$-chain from $q$ to $x$.
3. Since $R(f)$ is connected, there is a family of points 
   $\{h_i\}_{i=0}^m$ in $R(f)$ such that $h_0 = p$, $h_m = q$ and $d(h_i, h_{i+1}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $i < m$. Taking a $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$-chain from $h_i$ to itself and changing the
   last point to $h_{i+1}$ results in an $\varepsilon$-chain from $h_i$ to 
   $h_{i+1}$. Concatenating these chains yields an $\varepsilon$-chain
   from $p$ to $q$.

Combining the chains from 1, 3 and 2, we have an $\varepsilon$-chain
from $x$ to itself for arbitrary $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.
Therefore $R(f) = X$.

This may seem a very roundabout way of doing things. To see why this
is necessary, consider a case where $X$ is a circle and $f$ is a
homeomorphism where the fixed points form a semicircle. An 
$\varepsilon$-chain from a point to itself may really have to go
all the way around the circle, taking many "hops" between fixed points.
This is also an example where all points are chain-recurrent, but only
the fixed points are recurrent.