# a question on $\epsilon$ chain sequences

Tags: general-topology, analysis, dynamical-systems

I want to prove that if $X$ is a compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism which has a unique chain class $C$ then $X=C$.

> **Chain recurrence:** Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space and $ f : X \to X$ is a homeomorphism.
> By an $\epsilon$-chain from $x$ to $y$ in $X$ we mean a finite sequence $x_0 ,x_1 ... , x_k$ in $X$ with $x_0=x$ and $x_k=y$ such that :
> \begin{align}
> d(f(x_n) , x_{n+1})< \epsilon \; , \; n=0 ,..., k-1
> \end{align}
> a point $x \in X$ is said to be chain recurrent of $f$ , if for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $\epsilon$-chain from $x$ to $x$.
>
> **Chain class:** The set of chain recurrent points of $f$ is called the chain recurrent set of $f$, denoted $CR(f)$. Two points $x,y \in CR(f)$ are called chain equivalent, written $x \sim y$  if for any $\epsilon >0$ there is an $\epsilon$-chain from $x$ to $y$ and an $\epsilon$-chain from $y$ to $x$. This is equivalence relation on $CR(f)$. Each equivalence class is called a chain class.

My attempt:

By contradiction suppose $X \neq C$ we know that always $C \subseteq X$ so we have to prove that $X \subseteq C$ so by a contradiction we mean $X \not\subseteq C$ so there exists a point $x \in X$ such that it is not in $C$ this means there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that there is no $\epsilon$-chain between $x$ and the $m$ if we take $C=[m]$, I think we should find another chain class of $f$ to reach a contradiction. Could you please give me a hint if my solution is right or if not give me a solution?

My guess:
We have the following properties that I think they are useful:

> **1-** If $f$ is connected and $CR(f)=X$ then $X$ is a chain class.

> **2-** Any chain class is indecomposable, It means It can not be decomposed into a disjoint union of two non-empty compact invariant sets.

Comment: Can you prove that every point is chain recurrent? You will have to use the fact that $X$ is compact.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon  I think it's not that easy because the space $X$ is not connected. could we conclude that if $f$ has unique chain class then $X$ is connected?

Comment: Oh yes, good point. I will have to think a little more and get back, but at the outset, a single chain class should imply connectedness.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I made an edit on my post and added two properties which I think they are useful. have a look at them.

Comment: Is there a text that you are reading from? I love your question personally, and you have written it very well, +1.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Differentiable Dynamical Systems, Lan Wen

Comment: Thank you for the information,  I will look it up and see if there's anything that helps me!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Actually, it seems that this outline given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531566/dynamical-system-with-only-one-chain-component?rq=1) answers your question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Here $CR(f)=C$ because we just have one chain class, but how do we know it is connected?

Comment: Good point, I am not sure I can answer that.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I think we could use the fact that any chain class is indecomposabe. couldn't we?

Comment: That shows that $CR(f)$ is connected, right? Because $CR(f) = C$ and $C$ is indecomposable. And then from what I attached, $CR(f) = X$, since every point is chain recurrent. Maybe that problem is not a full duplicate, I will try to write an answer along those lines.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon If $CR(f)$ is connected then we can conclude from here that you showed me :

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531566/dynamical-system-with-only-one-chain-component?rq=1

Comment: Ok, so the final answer is this : if there's only one chain class, then that chain class equals $CR(f)$, and because every chain class is connected by property $2$, $CR(f)$ itself being the chain class is connected. Then we use the answer attached, which assumes that $CR(f)$ is connected for $f$ surjective, and $X$ compact, all of which are satisfied. So we can just copy the argument. Since you had to stretch a little more than the attached answer, I am not sure this qualifies as a full duplicate. You can write an answer to this effect.